# Leer un Fichero binario Java

Tags: java, archivo

La siguiente clase lo que hace es escribir un archivo binario con los datos de la persona los cuales se reciben por medio de un GUI y luego un boton llama a los metodos escribir y leer, los archivos se guardan de forma binaria, el problema es que al momento de leer sigue leyendo con los simbolos ASCII

```
package ei04_5;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import static sun.security.krb5.Confounder.bytes;

/**
 *
 * @author nicor
 */
public class ControlFichero {
    public void Escribir(String nombre,String apellido, String genero,String correo,String carrera)throws IOException{
        int aux = 0;
        File archivo = new File("Estudiante.bin");
        if(!archivo.exists()){
            try{
                
                aux = 1;
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archivo,true)));
                out.writeUTF("-Estudiante-");

               out.writeUTF("Estudiante");
               out.writeInt(aux);
               out.writeChars("(");
               out.writeUTF(nombre);
               out.writeUTF(apellido);
               out.writeUTF(genero);
               out.writeUTF(correo);
               out.writeUTF(carrera);
               out.writeChars(")");
               out.writeUTF("\n");
               
               out.close();


            
            }catch(EOFException ex){
            System.out.println("Error");
                }finally{}//cierre del fichero       
        }else{
            try{
                aux++;
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archivo,true)));
                
               out.writeUTF("T");
               out.writeInt(aux);
               out.writeChars("(");
               out.writeUTF(nombre);
               out.writeUTF(apellido);
               out.writeUTF(genero);
               out.writeUTF(correo);
               out.writeUTF(carrera);
               out.writeChars(")");
               out.writeUTF("\n");
               
               out.close();


                
                
            }catch(EOFException ex){
                System.out.println("Error");
                
            }
        
        }       
        
        
    }
          public void leer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
          String path = "./Triangulos2021.dat";
          DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("./Estudiante.bin")));
          //String rd = input.readLine();
              for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                  System.out.println(input.readLine());
              }
        }
```

Los datos se escriben de la siguiente forma
T    (@@  @@  @@  @yjRA   ) 
y en cuando leo el fichero, lo lee de la misma forma
como puedo hacer para que lo por de una forma decirlo lo traduzca a lenguaje normal, es menester usar
ficheros binarios para el ejercicio Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si escribes con UTF debes de leer con UTF

```
  public void leer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
     FileInputStream  fileIn = new FileInputStream("./Estudiante.bin");
     DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(fileIn);
     StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
     while(inputStream.available()>0) {
         buffer.append(inputStream.readUTF());           
     }
     System.out.println(buffer);
   }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me arrojo un error, sin embargo creo que asi funcionara, Enserio Muchas Gracias